# Не удалось прочитать строку 0, столбец 3 из CursorWindow, который имеет 1 строку и 3 столбца

Tags: android, база-данных, index

Я создал базу данных SQLite, и все выглядит нормально, пока я не добавлю «price» в список. Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне в этом.

```
public class SqliteDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 6;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "product";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";

    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";
    private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTPRICE = "productprice";
    private static final String COLUMN_QUANTITY = "quantity";

    public SqliteDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE  TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_QUANTITY + " INTEGER" + COLUMN_PRODUCTPRICE + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<Product> listProducts() {
        String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<Product> storeProducts = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                String name = cursor.getString(1);
                int quantity = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2));
                String price = cursor.getString(3);
                storeProducts.add(new Product(id, name, quantity, price));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        return storeProducts;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_QUANTITY, product.getQuantity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    }

    public void updateProduct(Product product) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_QUANTITY, product.getQuantity());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_PRODUCTS, values, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(product.getId())});
    }

    public Product findProduct(String name) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " = " + "name";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Product mProduct = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            String productName = cursor.getString(1);
            int productQuantity = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2));
            String productPrice = cursor.getString(3);
            mProduct = new Product(id, productName, productQuantity, productPrice);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return mProduct;
    }

    public void deleteProduct(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }
}

public class Product {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private String price;

    public Product(String name, int quantity, String price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Product(int id, String name, int quantity, String price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}

public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public TextView price;
    public ImageView deleteProduct;
    public ImageView editProduct;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_product_price);
        deleteProduct = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_product);
        editProduct = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_product);
    }
}
```

Ошибки которые выдает:

```
Failed to read row 0, column 3 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 3 columns.
06-26 19:26:34.571 31529-31529/com.gigamole.sample.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gigamole.sample.debug, PID: 31529
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 3 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Comment: onUpgrade возпроизводили? ну или переустанавливать приложение после добавления пробовали?

Comment: Вроде бы пишет, что у вас есть столбцы 0, 1, 2 (3 столбца), а вы хотите прочитать столбец 3.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид да пробовал ,тоже выдает ошибку .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `onCreate()`, создающий БД, вызывается только один раз, когда база данных еще не существует на устройстве (первый старт приложения).

Чтобы добавить/удалить/изменить имя в уже созданной ранее БД у таблицы или столбца, данные действия нужно прописывать в методе `onUpgrade()`. При этом, чтобы данный метод сработал, нужно повысить версию БД (значение  `DATABASE_VERSION` в вашем случае).

Все это справедливо для релизного приложения, если приложение на этапе разработки и вы единственный, кто его запускает, то гораздо проще будет удалить приложение с тестового устройства - это удалит и созданную БД. При следующем тестовом запуске снова сработает метод `onCreate()`, где вы можете написать новую структуру БД.