# Создание таблицы SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Есть код, он выводит информацию из БД, таблица называется messeg и все работает. Если меняю messeg на что либо еще, вылетает с ошибкой, пишет что нет таблицы. Как сделать проверку, что то типа если таблица с таким именем существует то "ОК" иначе создать ее ?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: Если вам требуется создание новых таблиц в процессе работы приложения, то с 99,9% вероятностью вы спроектировали свою базу данных неправильно. Структура БД - таблицы и их поля всегда статичны, задаются при создании БД и не изменяются в процессе всей работы. Если с новой версией приложения понадобилась новая структура таблиц, то изменение текущей структуры [производится в методе `onUpgrade()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684143/177345) класса `SQLiteOpenHelper`, чтобы изменения в БД были произведены, версия БД должна быть увеличена от текущей. Других причин добавлять таблицы быть не может.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из [SQLite документации](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messeg (id INTEGER, ...);
```