# Крашится Android приложение с SQLite на устройстве, на виртуальной машине все работает

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

Крашится приложение при считывании из таблицы в SQLite данных из последнего поля(COLUMN_NAME) при запуске на устройстве Huawei Mate 20 Lite. При запуске на виртуальной машине(Nexus 5x) ничего не вылетает и код, который добавил работает.

```
//именно из-за строки ниже идет краш. Если её закомменить - все ок
        userName = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME));
```

Либо проблема на моменте где заполняю базу, но там тоже все должно быть хорошо. Смущает то, что на виртуалке все отлично работает.

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE users (" + COLUMN_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_LOG
            + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PASS + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_LEVEL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT);");
    // добавление начальных данных
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE +" (" + COLUMN_LOG
            + ", " + COLUMN_PASS + ", " + COLUMN_LEVEL + ", " + COLUMN_NAME + ") VALUES ('admin', '12345', '1', 'viktor');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+ TABLE +" (" + COLUMN_LOG
            + ", " + COLUMN_PASS  + ", " + COLUMN_LEVEL + ", " + COLUMN_NAME + ") VALUES ('user', '12345', '2', 'ivan');");

}
```

Весь метод:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    // тосты для вывода всплывающего хинта авторизации на экране.
    Toast logOk = Toast.makeText(this, "Login accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    Toast logFalse = Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong data, check please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        //создаю интенты для перехода к АдминАктивити и ЮзерАктивити
        Intent adminIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminActivity.class);
        Intent userIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class);

    //перехожу к первой записи в таблице
    userCursor.moveToFirst();

    // сверяю в цикле логин+пароль с записяпи в таблице
    for (int i = 0; i < userCursor.getCount(); i++) {
        loginGet = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LOG));
        passGet = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PASS));
        //в переменной userLevel храню данные о уровне пользователя "1" - Admin, "2" - User
        userLevel = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LEVEL));
        userName = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME));

                if ((inLog.getText().toString().equals(loginGet)) && (inPas.getText().toString().equals(passGet))) {
                    logOk.show();
                    logYes=true;
                    //проверяем кто логинится(если админ - переходим на АдминАктивити, иначе на ЮзерАктивити
                            if(userLevel.equals("1")){
                                adminIntent.putExtra("uName", userName);
                                startActivity(adminIntent);
                            } else {
                                userIntent.putExtra("uName", userName);
                                startActivity(userIntent);

                            }
                break;
                } else {
                  //перехожу к следующей записи в таблице
                  logYes=false;
                  userCursor.moveToNext();
                }
    }
    if(logYes==false) logFalse.show();

}
```

За "порядочность" кода и велосипеды(о некоторых сам знаю, возможно исправлю) прошу не ругать, проект учебный для универа. Нужно лишь чтобы работало.
Остальные активити не показываю, т.к. крашится даже если логин и пасс не вводить, то бишь момент, где передаю данные в другую активити, даже не задействован.
Весь код работал безупречно, до момента пока не добавил в БД еще один столбик "COLUMN NAME".
Логи:

```
2019-05-18 21:13:56.931 6651-6651/? E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-05-18 21:13:56.931 6651-6651/? E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-05-18 21:13:56.931 6651-6651/? D/Editor: sendUpdateSelection: Spannable name is SpannableStringBuilder, text length:0
2019-05-18 21:13:56.931 6651-6651/? D/Editor: sendUpdateSelection: selectionStart=0, selectionEnd=0, candStart=-1, candEnd-1
2019-05-18 21:13:58.005 6651-6651/com.example.login V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
2019-05-18 21:13:58.022 6651-6651/com.example.login E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 4 columns.
2019-05-18 21:13:58.022 6651-6651/com.example.login D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-05-18 21:13:58.024 6651-6651/com.example.login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.login, PID: 6651
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6329)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25002)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6329) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25002) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:440)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at com.example.login.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:83)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6329) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25002) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:809) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

Comment: Логи показывают на 83 строку. Это строка, что я указал в начале поста:
`userName = userCursor.getString(userCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME));`

Comment: Скомпилил на другое устройство (huawei p9 lite Android 7.0) Тоже все замечательно работает. На предыдущем устройстве андроид 8.1.0. Предполагаю, что в этом проблема.

Comment: предполагаю, что [проблема в этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/684143/177345)

Comment: pavloff, Да, спасибо. Проблема оказалось почти в этом. Но я всегда удалял предыдущее приложение и компилил заново. Почему это не удаляло БД? 
Помогло лишь то, что я в коде изменил название создаваемой бд.

Comment: возможно вы помещаете свою базу не по умолчанию (в выделенную приложению область, которая очищается при его удалении), а в общедоступное хранилище, как SD-карта. тогда базу нужно было удалить вручную.

Comment: Удалял также все данные от приложения. SD карты даже нет в телефоне, своей памяти хватает. Да и при создании бд никаких путей не указывал, так что должна создаваться в корне проекта. Чудеса.